# C++ : Return string value through function call on a class object

Tags: c++

I've started learning C++, and try to make a game while doing so, in order to have something exciting to do. I've made my project (using Netbeans), with main and another class to handle some of the logic.
Before I went to deep into the logics, I made a test to see if everything were as supposed.
Compiling went through without problems, but when I run my project I don't see the wanted text in the console.
I've tried `cout` it from `main.cpp` as well as the object class itself, but no luck either way (no output from `getCharacterName`).

I would be happy if you'd have time to take a quick look at my code below and point me in the right direction.

main.cpp

```
#include "character/info.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

info * character;

int main() {
    character = new info("PlayerName");
    character->getCharacterName();
    delete character;
}
```

info.h

```
#ifndef INFO_H
#define INFO_H

#include <iostream>

class info {
public:
    info(std::string) {};
    ~info() {};
    std::string getCharacterName() {};
}
#endif  /* INFO_H */
```

info.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class info {

        static string characterName;

    info(std::string charName) {
        cout<<"starting character";
        info::characterName = charName;
        cout<<"character made";
    }

    ~info() {
        cout<<"Object removed";
    }

public: void getCharacterName() {
        cout<< info::characterName;
    }
};
```

As mentioned earlier the last function has looked like below aswell, with the 'cout' in the main instead:

```
public: std::string getCharacterName() {
        return info::characterName;
}
```

Thanks in advance

//Pyracell

Comment: you should avoid to declare global variables as you do with: `info * character;`, but instead declare it inside the `main()` function where you use it. The idea being, declare a symbol where you use it.

Comment: you claim, that your code compiles, but it's not not even near to being compilable.

Comment: @zmo I've removed the global variable and declare it in the main now. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich I've stripped some of the logic in order to make a light example for you to comment on, so that I could get the necessary understanding. I'm sorry the example  wasn't compilable. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared empty functions in your .h file. When you separate the declaration and the definition you need to do like this:

info.h

```
#ifndef INFO_H
#define INFO_H

#include <string>

class info {
public:
    info(std::string);
    ~info();
    std::string getCharacterName();
private
    std::string name;
};

#endif
```

info.cpp

```
#include "info.h"

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

info::info(std::string charName) : name(charName) {
    cout<<"character made";
}

info::~info() {
    cout<<"Object removed";
}

std::string info::getCharacterName() {
    return name;
}
```

As a side note, there is a couple things that are worth mentioning I think:

- In your `main.cpp`, you declare a global variable to hold your character, this is generally something that we try to avoid
- Still in your `main.cpp`, you create your character using new where doing `info("MyCharacterName");` would probably be enough
- Last point above shows that you declare an info but it is in fact a character that your class is modeling, maybe the class name info is not relevant
- It is generally a good practise to start class names with an upper case

Keep working on this project, the best way to learn is to practice again and again...

Comment: Where is `info::characterName` declared? Where is it defined?

Comment: I just copied and paste the code without removing the content. It needs to be changed as well (well, most of the original code should be changed anyway)

Comment: There, it should be a bit better now. I still think that `info` is not a good name for this class but it's not for me to decide.

Comment: @Uflex thanks a lot. This helped me out. Just a bit of a wake up call, with the classes working this way.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues here:

- `character` is a global (avoid globals unless necessary)
- `character` is allocated with `new` (use automatic storage when possible)
- the header defines the methods as empty (due to the `{}`)
- `getCharacterName` in `info.cpp` has a different return value than the one in the header
- `characterName` is a `static` and it only appears in `info.cpp` (in this case it should be an ordinary member; in any case, it needs to be declared in the header)
- in the `info.cpp` file you use the `class` keyword (that will declare a new class `Info` meaning your code either won't compile or it will be very strange indeed), use `info:info(std::string charName)`, `info::~info()` and `std::string info::getCharacterName()` to define the functions (check Uflex answer for details)

Comment: Thank you for the time you put into this post. I will go through every line, and try to optimize my code/making it clean.